# ViewPager issue: To finish Activity on swiping last page

Tags: android

I want to finish an `Activity` when a user is in last fragment inside of a `view Pager` and try to swipe for next screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your adapter code please/

Comment: Thanks a lot Ricardo. :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any direct way but you can include a blank page at last index of ViewPager. So when user comes to this blank page, which most probably will be a fragment, call activity finish.

Comment: Hi Rajen    Thanks lot .... I did this as of now as it was very urgent to fix this issue but we need to find exact solution something like mentioned in below code.

Answer (score 0):

First when you create your `ViewPager` fragment in your `ViewPagerAdapter` check if it's last fragment like below and pass it as a parameter to your fragment.

```
final Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
if(position == items.size()-1){
   final Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putBoolean("isLast",true);
   fragment.setArguments(args);
}
return fragment;
```

In your `Fragment`'s `onCreate` method get arguments and check if this is your `ViewPager`'s last fragment like below:

```
boolean isLast = false;
final Bundle args = getArguments();
if(args != null){
   isLast = args.getBooleanExtra("isLast",false);
}
```

In your fragment's `onCreateView` method when you inflate your method if this fragment `isLast` ( `isLast == true`) set a touch listener to your view and detect swipe event like below:

```
if(isLast){
final int swipeBuffer = 50;
int oldX = 0;
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            swtich(event.getType()){
               case MotionEvent.MOTION_DOWN:
                  oldX = event.getX();
                  break;

               case MotionEvent.MOTION_UP:
                  int newX = event.getX();
                  if(oldX - newX >= swipeBuffer){
                     // This means user trying to swipe
                     getActivity().finish();
                  }
                  break;
            }
                return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if this's a proper solution but i think this may help you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for sharing code as it did not work right now, but i got your logic, As i understand we need to change little bit inside onTouch listener.